# para que serve o '@' no php?

Tags: php

Olá, sou iniciante em php e me surgiu uma duvida que não consegui encontrar uma resposta plausível no google; para que serve o "@" no php?
esta vendo um tutorial de como funciona o `MYSQLI` no php e no video o rapaz usou o codigo `@mysqli_connect`.
alguem pode me explicar?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ele suprime as mensagens de erro.
Veja em [Operadores de controle de erro](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.operators.errorcontrol.php)

Exemplo:

```
<?php
/* Erro de arquivo intencional */
$my_file = @file ('arquivo_nao_existente') or
    die ("Falha abrindo arquivo: '$php_errormsg'");

// Isto funciona para qualquer expressão, não apenas para funções:
$value = @$cache[$key];
// você não receberá nenhum aviso se a chave $key não existir.

?>
```